# How to implement CI/CD using Jenkins for non GitHub repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have repo in my server without GitHub and just want to check that is there any possibility of implementing the Jenkins CI/CD for this repo.

If possible, please direct me to some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is not a pre-requisite forJenkins nor Git. You can use amy remote repository store, including [local or file](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_protocols) for your pipeline, as documented in the [git plugin configuration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-configuration), `repository url`